# Can't upload files to Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I have managed to set my environment variables for Digital ocean,

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
# static settings
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I also ran:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

And it ran successfully, all files uploaded to Digital ocean.

But my challenge now is that, when I upload Images with Django Admin, they don't upload to Digital ocean, they rather upload to local folders.

What am I missing in the configuration?

Comment: if i may ask, what version of django are you using and how does your overral DO-SPACES looks like. i've been having issues serving staticfiles from m django from DO-SPACES for over a week now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media configuration is missing, you can use this.
In your Django settings file, add the following configuration options:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

That's it! Your Django application should now use DigitalOcean Spaces for media storage. You can test it by uploading a file through your application's admin panel or using a view that saves a file to your media directory. The file should be uploaded to your DigitalOcean Space instead of your server's file system.